# Responsive navigation bar using window resize

Tags: jquery, css

Any suggestions on using an efficient approach to window resize? I am doing a responsive navigation bar. When less than 480px, by toggling the navigation to minimize - display is set to hidden. If I then grow the screen to greater than 480, the navigation stays in its hidden state. To fix this I've added a window resize function, whenever the screen is greater than 480 the list goes back to its initial value. I feel like this could be heavily improved and is wasting a lot of performance.

```
<div class = "dropdown">
        <div class = "icon">
            <img src ="menu.png" class = "text" align = "right">
        </div>
        <ul class = "header-li"> 
            <li><a href ="#1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  


$(".icon").click(function(){
    $(".header-li", ".dropdown").slideToggle(); 
});


$(window).on('resize',function(event){
    var windowSize = $(this).width();

    if (windowSize > 480){
        $(".header-li").css('display','');
    }
}); 

Media query max 480px

display icon
list display:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `window.resize` is correct, however, you'll also want to add an `else` condition for replacing the style once the window shrinks back down.

However, I recommend using a media query for this as it is much more efficient in comparison and can be done with pure CSS.

Run the snippet below and click "Full Screen," then resize your browser window to view the demo in action.

```css
/* The default view (in this case, for mobile) */
.header-li {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

/* When the window is greater than 480px wide */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .header-li {
    background:green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-li"> </div>
```

Learn more about [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)